# How to listen redis list event with redisson and ZIO

Tags: scala, redis, redisson, zio

With Radisson, simply receiving events is enough to add new items to the list. To do this, you need to do the following:

```
object Test extends App {
  val redisson = Redisson.create()
  val events = redisson.getQueue[String]("minio_events", new StringCodec())
  events.addListener(new ListAddListener() {
    override def onListAdd(o: String): Unit = println(o)
  })
}
```

Difficulties begin when it needs to be wrapped in ZIO. How can I wrap this event in ZIO or ZStream to start the chain of event processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Redisson supports converting the `RedissonClient` into a reactive streams client which there is a zio-interop for. But if you just want to work directly with the java interface I think you can do something like this (note I haven't actually tested this):

```
object Test extends zio.App {
   def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, ExitCode] = 
       (for {
         // Construct the client in the scope of the stream so it shuts down when done
         c <- ZStream.managed(ZManaged.makeEffect(Redisson.create())(_.shutdown()))

         // Variant of effectAsync* that lets you specify an interrupter
         s <- ZStream.effectAsyncInterrupt[Any, Nothing, String] { k =>
           val queue = c.getQueue[String]("", new StringCodec())
           val listenerId = queue.addListener(new ListAddListener {

             // Invoke the callback by passing in a ZIO with a single chunk
             def onListAdd(name: String): Unit = k(ZIO.succeed(Chunk.single(name)))
           })

           // Return a cancellation handler.
           Left(UIO(queue.removeListener(listenerId)))
        }
      } { zio.console.putStrLn(s) }).exitCode
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "supports converting the RedissonClient into a reactive streams client which there is a zio-interop for"? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ZStream is pull based, that means you'll have to pull the data from `minio_events` in some way

```scala
val redisson = Redisson.create()    
val bqueue : RQueue[String] = redisson.getQueue("minio_events", new StringCodec())
    
val pollQueue = 
  ZIO
    .effect(Option(bqueue.poll())) // RQueue.poll returns null if the queue is empty
    .someOrFail(NoElementsOnStream)
```

This creates a `ZIO[Any, Throwable, String]` representing your polling operation which can now be turned into a `ZStream` by calling the `ZStream.fromEffect` method

```scala
ZStream
  .fromEffect(pollQueue)
  .foreach(s => putStrLn(s))
  .exitCode
```

If you place this code inside a `zio.App` main function, you'll see that it runs only once. So we need to make it run forever and retry it until if finds another element

```scala
ZStream
  .fromEffect(pollQueue)
  .retry(Schedule.spaced(1.second))
  .forever
  .foreach(s => putStrLn(s))  
  .exitCode
```

Comment: Yes, I went on the same way. But the question was a little different, is it possible to subscribe to the add event? It seems to me that such a solution puts a heavy load on the processor.

Comment: I think it's less of a problem than you think it is. Yes, would could probably space your pulls from the queue by a few seconds or maybe get n items at a time, but adopting a pull based strategy has the advantage of backpressuring when your sink becomes slower.